# Populating a Linked List with numbers 1000-9999

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

So I need to populate my Linked List called Candidate, with numbers 1000-9999. 
I'm aware of how to do it for arrays with a foor loop, i'm assuming it's similar here.

I have a setter method called setInfo, and set link method made in a node class, they are here.

```
public void setInfo(int info){ //Info Setter
        this.info = info;
    }
public void setLink(LLIntegerNode link){ //Link setter
        this.link = link;
    }
```

My attempt is here

```
LLIntegerNode candidate;   //Node class and Linked List named candidate
for(int j =9999; j >=1000; j--){ 
LLIntegerNode canNode = new LLIntegerNode(j, null); //new node
            candidate.setInfo(canNode);
        }
```

Something is wrong, I need to set all the numbers to populate into this new node but i'm not sure how to do it right...

I get an error at setInfo, and it says `the method setInfo(int) in the type LLIntegerNode is not applicable for the arguments (LLIntegerNode)`

here is my LLIntegerNode class

```
public class LLIntegerNode{

    private int info; // info inside node
    private LLIntegerNode link; //create a link for nodes

    public LLIntegerNode(int info, LLIntegerNode link){ //Constructor
        this.info = info;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void setInfo(int info){ //Info Setter
        this.info = info;
    }

    public int getInfo(){ //Info Getter
        return info;
    }

    public void setLink(LLIntegerNode link){ //Link setter
        this.link = link;
    }

    public LLIntegerNode getLink(){ //Link getter
        return link;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please add the `LLIntegerNode` class definition to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet won't work:

```
LLIntegerNode candidate;   //Node class and Linked List named candidate
for(int j =9999; j >=1000; j--){ 
LLIntegerNode canNode = new LLIntegerNode(j, null); //new node
    candidate.setInfo(canNode);
}
```

There are two reasons

- `candidate` is not initialised
- Even if it's initialised, `for` loop will keep on overwriting the values.

What you really want is the following (if I understand the question correctly):

```
LLIntegerNode candidate = new LLIntegerNode();
for(int j =9999; j >=1000; j--){ 
    LLIntegerNode element = new LLIntegerNode(j, null); //new node
    candidate.setLink(element);
    candidate = element;
}
```

This will add the nodes into the list.

Comment: That probably would work but i'm not allowed to use the LinkedList util class.. therefore I can't use add

Comment: okay, now i'm a little confused on what to do with my linked list that I was using. "candidate" how do i make sure all the nodes link to that?

Comment: I have renamed `head` to `candidate`. It's basically the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a cursor to add elements to the linked list. Otherwise you will only overwrite the same element in the list.

```
LLIntegerNode head = new LLIntegerNode(9999, null);
LLIntegerNode cursor = head;
for(int j = 9998; j >= 1000; j--){
    LLIntegerNode canNode = new LLIntegerNode(j, null); //new node
    cursor.setLink(canNode);
    cursor = canNode;
}
```

Comment: but my LinkedList candidate is not used here

Comment: You can rename `head` to `candidate` assuming `candidate` is the head of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes an `int`, so pass the value for `j` into it instead.

> ```
> public void setInfo(int info) { // Info Setter
>     this.info = info;
> }
> ```

```
candidate.setInfo(j);
```

The error tells you that you are passing a `LLIntegerNode` into a method that only accepts an `int`.

> method setInfo(int) in the type LLIntegerNode is not applicable for the arguments (LLIntegerNode)

---

You can add this `toString()` method to your class `LLIntegerNode`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s -> %d", link, info);
}
```

And simply execute the following class.

```
public class LLIntegerNodeDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 1000;
        int end = 2000;
        LLIntegerNode head = null;

        for (int info = end - 1; info >= start; info--) {
            head = new LLIntegerNode(info, head);
        }

        System.out.println(head);
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
null -> 1999 -> 1998 -> 1997 -> 1996 -> 1995 -> 1994 -> 1993 -> 1992 -> 1991 -> 1990 -> 1989 -> 1988 -> 1987 -> 1986 -> 1985 -> 1984 -> 1983 -> 1982 -> 1981 -> 1980 -> 1979 -> 1978 -> 1977 -> 1976 -> 1975 -> 1974 -> 1973 -> 1972 -> 1971 -> 1970 -> 1969 -> 1968 -> 1967 -> 1966 -> 1965 -> 1964 -> 1963 -> 1962 -> 1961 -> 1960 -> 1959 -> 1958 -> 1957 -> 1956 -> 1955 -> 1954 -> 1953 -> 1952 -> 1951 -> 1950 -> 1949 -> 1948 -> 1947 -> 1946 -> 1945 -> 1944 -> 1943 -> 1942 -> 1941 -> 1940 -> 1939 -> 1938 -> 1937 -> 1936 -> 1935 -> 1934 -> 1933 -> 1932 -> 1931 -> 1930 -> 1929 -> 1928 -> 1927 -> 1926 -> 1925 -> 1924 -> 1923 -> 1922 -> 1921 -> 1920 -> 1919 -> 1918 -> 1917 -> 1916 -> 1915 -> 1914 -> 1913 -> 1912 -> 1911 -> 1910 -> 1909 -> 1908 -> 1907 -> 1906 -> 1905 -> 1904 -> 1903 -> 1902 -> 1901 -> 1900 -> 1899 -> 1898 -> 1897 -> 1896 -> 1895 -> 1894 -> 1893 -> 1892 -> 1891 -> 1890 -> 1889 -> 1888 -> 1887 -> 1886 -> 1885 -> 1884 -> 1883 -> 1882 -> 1881 -> 1880 -> 1879 -> 1878 -> 1877 -> 1876 -> 1875 -> 1874 -> 1873 -> 1872 -> 1871 -> 1870 -> 1869 -> 1868 -> 1867 -> 1866 -> 1865 -> 1864 -> 1863 -> 1862 -> 1861 -> 1860 -> 1859 -> 1858 -> 1857 -> 1856 -> 1855 -> 1854 -> 1853 -> 1852 -> 1851 -> 1850 -> 1849 -> 1848 -> 1847 -> 1846 -> 1845 -> 1844 -> 1843 -> 1842 -> 1841 -> 1840 -> 1839 -> 1838 -> 1837 -> 1836 -> 1835 -> 1834 -> 1833 -> 1832 -> 1831 -> 1830 -> 1829 -> 1828 -> 1827 -> 1826 -> 1825 -> 1824 -> 1823 -> 1822 -> 1821 -> 1820 -> 1819 -> 1818 -> 1817 -> 1816 -> 1815 -> 1814 -> 1813 -> 1812 -> 1811 -> 1810 -> 1809 -> 1808 -> 1807 -> 1806 -> 1805 -> 1804 -> 1803 -> 1802 -> 1801 -> 1800 -> 1799 -> 1798 -> 1797 -> 1796 -> 1795 -> 1794 -> 1793 -> 1792 -> 1791 -> 1790 -> 1789 -> 1788 -> 1787 -> 1786 -> 1785 -> 1784 -> 1783 -> 1782 -> 1781 -> 1780 -> 1779 -> 1778 -> 1777 -> 1776 -> 1775 -> 1774 -> 1773 -> 1772 -> 1771 -> 1770 -> 1769 -> 1768 -> 1767 -> 1766 -> 1765 -> 1764 -> 1763 -> 1762 -> 1761 -> 1760 -> 1759 -> 1758 -> 1757 -> 1756 -> 1755 -> 1754 -> 1753 -> 1752 -> 1751 -> 1750 -> 1749 -> 1748 -> 1747 -> 1746 -> 1745 -> 1744 -> 1743 -> 1742 -> 1741 -> 1740 -> 1739 -> 1738 -> 1737 -> 1736 -> 1735 -> 1734 -> 1733 -> 1732 -> 1731 -> 1730 -> 1729 -> 1728 -> 1727 -> 1726 -> 1725 -> 1724 -> 1723 -> 1722 -> 1721 -> 1720 -> 1719 -> 1718 -> 1717 -> 1716 -> 1715 -> 1714 -> 1713 -> 1712 -> 1711 -> 1710 -> 1709 -> 1708 -> 1707 -> 1706 -> 1705 -> 1704 -> 1703 -> 1702 -> 1701 -> 1700 -> 1699 -> 1698 -> 1697 -> 1696 -> 1695 -> 1694 -> 1693 -> 1692 -> 1691 -> 1690 -> 1689 -> 1688 -> 1687 -> 1686 -> 1685 -> 1684 -> 1683 -> 1682 -> 1681 -> 1680 -> 1679 -> 1678 -> 1677 -> 1676 -> 1675 -> 1674 -> 1673 -> 1672 -> 1671 -> 1670 -> 1669 -> 1668 -> 1667 -> 1666 -> 1665 -> 1664 -> 1663 -> 1662 -> 1661 -> 1660 -> 1659 -> 1658 -> 1657 -> 1656 -> 1655 -> 1654 -> 1653 -> 1652 -> 1651 -> 1650 -> 1649 -> 1648 -> 1647 -> 1646 -> 1645 -> 1644 -> 1643 -> 1642 -> 1641 -> 1640 -> 1639 -> 1638 -> 1637 -> 1636 -> 1635 -> 1634 -> 1633 -> 1632 -> 1631 -> 1630 -> 1629 -> 1628 -> 1627 -> 1626 -> 1625 -> 1624 -> 1623 -> 1622 -> 1621 -> 1620 -> 1619 -> 1618 -> 1617 -> 1616 -> 1615 -> 1614 -> 1613 -> 1612 -> 1611 -> 1610 -> 1609 -> 1608 -> 1607 -> 1606 -> 1605 -> 1604 -> 1603 -> 1602 -> 1601 -> 1600 -> 1599 -> 1598 -> 1597 -> 1596 -> 1595 -> 1594 -> 1593 -> 1592 -> 1591 -> 1590 -> 1589 -> 1588 -> 1587 -> 1586 -> 1585 -> 1584 -> 1583 -> 1582 -> 1581 -> 1580 -> 1579 -> 1578 -> 1577 -> 1576 -> 1575 -> 1574 -> 1573 -> 1572 -> 1571 -> 1570 -> 1569 -> 1568 -> 1567 -> 1566 -> 1565 -> 1564 -> 1563 -> 1562 -> 1561 -> 1560 -> 1559 -> 1558 -> 1557 -> 1556 -> 1555 -> 1554 -> 1553 -> 1552 -> 1551 -> 1550 -> 1549 -> 1548 -> 1547 -> 1546 -> 1545 -> 1544 -> 1543 -> 1542 -> 1541 -> 1540 -> 1539 -> 1538 -> 1537 -> 1536 -> 1535 -> 1534 -> 1533 -> 1532 -> 1531 -> 1530 -> 1529 -> 1528 -> 1527 -> 1526 -> 1525 -> 1524 -> 1523 -> 1522 -> 1521 -> 1520 -> 1519 -> 1518 -> 1517 -> 1516 -> 1515 -> 1514 -> 1513 -> 1512 -> 1511 -> 1510 -> 1509 -> 1508 -> 1507 -> 1506 -> 1505 -> 1504 -> 1503 -> 1502 -> 1501 -> 1500 -> 1499 -> 1498 -> 1497 -> 1496 -> 1495 -> 1494 -> 1493 -> 1492 -> 1491 -> 1490 -> 1489 -> 1488 -> 1487 -> 1486 -> 1485 -> 1484 -> 1483 -> 1482 -> 1481 -> 1480 -> 1479 -> 1478 -> 1477 -> 1476 -> 1475 -> 1474 -> 1473 -> 1472 -> 1471 -> 1470 -> 1469 -> 1468 -> 1467 -> 1466 -> 1465 -> 1464 -> 1463 -> 1462 -> 1461 -> 1460 -> 1459 -> 1458 -> 1457 -> 1456 -> 1455 -> 1454 -> 1453 -> 1452 -> 1451 -> 1450 -> 1449 -> 1448 -> 1447 -> 1446 -> 1445 -> 1444 -> 1443 -> 1442 -> 1441 -> 1440 -> 1439 -> 1438 -> 1437 -> 1436 -> 1435 -> 1434 -> 1433 -> 1432 -> 1431 -> 1430 -> 1429 -> 1428 -> 1427 -> 1426 -> 1425 -> 1424 -> 1423 -> 1422 -> 1421 -> 1420 -> 1419 -> 1418 -> 1417 -> 1416 -> 1415 -> 1414 -> 1413 -> 1412 -> 1411 -> 1410 -> 1409 -> 1408 -> 1407 -> 1406 -> 1405 -> 1404 -> 1403 -> 1402 -> 1401 -> 1400 -> 1399 -> 1398 -> 1397 -> 1396 -> 1395 -> 1394 -> 1393 -> 1392 -> 1391 -> 1390 -> 1389 -> 1388 -> 1387 -> 1386 -> 1385 -> 1384 -> 1383 -> 1382 -> 1381 -> 1380 -> 1379 -> 1378 -> 1377 -> 1376 -> 1375 -> 1374 -> 1373 -> 1372 -> 1371 -> 1370 -> 1369 -> 1368 -> 1367 -> 1366 -> 1365 -> 1364 -> 1363 -> 1362 -> 1361 -> 1360 -> 1359 -> 1358 -> 1357 -> 1356 -> 1355 -> 1354 -> 1353 -> 1352 -> 1351 -> 1350 -> 1349 -> 1348 -> 1347 -> 1346 -> 1345 -> 1344 -> 1343 -> 1342 -> 1341 -> 1340 -> 1339 -> 1338 -> 1337 -> 1336 -> 1335 -> 1334 -> 1333 -> 1332 -> 1331 -> 1330 -> 1329 -> 1328 -> 1327 -> 1326 -> 1325 -> 1324 -> 1323 -> 1322 -> 1321 -> 1320 -> 1319 -> 1318 -> 1317 -> 1316 -> 1315 -> 1314 -> 1313 -> 1312 -> 1311 -> 1310 -> 1309 -> 1308 -> 1307 -> 1306 -> 1305 -> 1304 -> 1303 -> 1302 -> 1301 -> 1300 -> 1299 -> 1298 -> 1297 -> 1296 -> 1295 -> 1294 -> 1293 -> 1292 -> 1291 -> 1290 -> 1289 -> 1288 -> 1287 -> 1286 -> 1285 -> 1284 -> 1283 -> 1282 -> 1281 -> 1280 -> 1279 -> 1278 -> 1277 -> 1276 -> 1275 -> 1274 -> 1273 -> 1272 -> 1271 -> 1270 -> 1269 -> 1268 -> 1267 -> 1266 -> 1265 -> 1264 -> 1263 -> 1262 -> 1261 -> 1260 -> 1259 -> 1258 -> 1257 -> 1256 -> 1255 -> 1254 -> 1253 -> 1252 -> 1251 -> 1250 -> 1249 -> 1248 -> 1247 -> 1246 -> 1245 -> 1244 -> 1243 -> 1242 -> 1241 -> 1240 -> 1239 -> 1238 -> 1237 -> 1236 -> 1235 -> 1234 -> 1233 -> 1232 -> 1231 -> 1230 -> 1229 -> 1228 -> 1227 -> 1226 -> 1225 -> 1224 -> 1223 -> 1222 -> 1221 -> 1220 -> 1219 -> 1218 -> 1217 -> 1216 -> 1215 -> 1214 -> 1213 -> 1212 -> 1211 -> 1210 -> 1209 -> 1208 -> 1207 -> 1206 -> 1205 -> 1204 -> 1203 -> 1202 -> 1201 -> 1200 -> 1199 -> 1198 -> 1197 -> 1196 -> 1195 -> 1194 -> 1193 -> 1192 -> 1191 -> 1190 -> 1189 -> 1188 -> 1187 -> 1186 -> 1185 -> 1184 -> 1183 -> 1182 -> 1181 -> 1180 -> 1179 -> 1178 -> 1177 -> 1176 -> 1175 -> 1174 -> 1173 -> 1172 -> 1171 -> 1170 -> 1169 -> 1168 -> 1167 -> 1166 -> 1165 -> 1164 -> 1163 -> 1162 -> 1161 -> 1160 -> 1159 -> 1158 -> 1157 -> 1156 -> 1155 -> 1154 -> 1153 -> 1152 -> 1151 -> 1150 -> 1149 -> 1148 -> 1147 -> 1146 -> 1145 -> 1144 -> 1143 -> 1142 -> 1141 -> 1140 -> 1139 -> 1138 -> 1137 -> 1136 -> 1135 -> 1134 -> 1133 -> 1132 -> 1131 -> 1130 -> 1129 -> 1128 -> 1127 -> 1126 -> 1125 -> 1124 -> 1123 -> 1122 -> 1121 -> 1120 -> 1119 -> 1118 -> 1117 -> 1116 -> 1115 -> 1114 -> 1113 -> 1112 -> 1111 -> 1110 -> 1109 -> 1108 -> 1107 -> 1106 -> 1105 -> 1104 -> 1103 -> 1102 -> 1101 -> 1100 -> 1099 -> 1098 -> 1097 -> 1096 -> 1095 -> 1094 -> 1093 -> 1092 -> 1091 -> 1090 -> 1089 -> 1088 -> 1087 -> 1086 -> 1085 -> 1084 -> 1083 -> 1082 -> 1081 -> 1080 -> 1079 -> 1078 -> 1077 -> 1076 -> 1075 -> 1074 -> 1073 -> 1072 -> 1071 -> 1070 -> 1069 -> 1068 -> 1067 -> 1066 -> 1065 -> 1064 -> 1063 -> 1062 -> 1061 -> 1060 -> 1059 -> 1058 -> 1057 -> 1056 -> 1055 -> 1054 -> 1053 -> 1052 -> 1051 -> 1050 -> 1049 -> 1048 -> 1047 -> 1046 -> 1045 -> 1044 -> 1043 -> 1042 -> 1041 -> 1040 -> 1039 -> 1038 -> 1037 -> 1036 -> 1035 -> 1034 -> 1033 -> 1032 -> 1031 -> 1030 -> 1029 -> 1028 -> 1027 -> 1026 -> 1025 -> 1024 -> 1023 -> 1022 -> 1021 -> 1020 -> 1019 -> 1018 -> 1017 -> 1016 -> 1015 -> 1014 -> 1013 -> 1012 -> 1011 -> 1010 -> 1009 -> 1008 -> 1007 -> 1006 -> 1005 -> 1004 -> 1003 -> 1002 -> 1001 -> 1000
```

Comment: okay, so I need to pass j into my new node in the int parameter and into my linked list candidate? is that correct?

Comment: @maxbr7t Does the list not hold "integers"? If it does, then yes, you need to set the info to the number value in the loop.

Comment: yes the list is supposed to hold ints from 1000-9999. thanks for clearing it up for me, but the compiler tells me that the new node i tried to create is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I can see that are causing you problems. I think a good first step would be write out some pseudo code/write out the steps that are needed for what you are trying to accomplish.

So what do we need before we get started?

- We need a reference to the head of the list, otherwise we lose the other nodes.
- we need a reference to the tail of the list onto which we will append new nodes
- at the beginning, the head and the tail are the same node.

Once you have that, you can go about adding the remaining values to the list. To do this you will want to, for each remaining number:

- create a new node with the next value in line
- set the new node to be the node the tail reference links to
- set the tail reference to be that new node

---

```
LLIntegerNode candidate = new LLIntegerNode(1000, null);//the head of the linked list
LLIntegerNode tail = candidate;//the tail reference

for(int j = 10001; j <= 9999; j++){
    LLIntegerNode newNode = new LLIntegerNode(j, null);
    tail.setLink(newNode);
    tail = newNode;
}
```

---

In a Singly linked list as you are building here, every node only knows of the next node in the chain. It keeps no reference to the previous node. If you do not keep a reference to the head of the list and constantly update 'candidate to be the new node you just added to the end of the list, you will end up pointing at only the last element of the list.

Since you want the list to be going from 1000 - 9999 you need to build the list from front to back. If you did not want to use a second reference to the tail of the list and build it from back to front, you would need to make 'candidate' the node the new node points to and then update 'candidate' to point at the new node you have created.

```
LLIntegerNode candidate = new LLIntegerNode(9999, null);
for(int j = 9998; int j >= 1000; j--){
    LLIntegerNode newNode = new LLIntegerNode(j, candidate);
    candidate = newNode;
}
```